# Google Maps (v3) "MarkerClusterer": Add Circle to visible markers only

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am trying to draw a "circle" around "visible markers only" when using the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) library for Google Maps v3.

The library "clusters" (groups) markers which can be used to improve performance and load time.

"MarkerClusterer" example:

[image: Example of "MarkerClusterer"]

I do not want to draw the circle around every marker as it takes to long and negates the benefits of the library.

I can bind a circles to markers with the javascript below.

**My question is**: how to bind the circle to the marker but only when the MarkerClusterer library "decides" to draw an individual marker on the map (as opposed to when it displays a cluster group instead).

```
    // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        radius: 30.48,    // 150 feet in metres
        fillColor: '#FACC2E',
        strokeColor: '#FACC2E',
        strokeOpacity: 0.75
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Circle will not be drawn unless you set the `map`-property to a `google.maps.Map` .

So don't set the `map`-property and bind the `map`-property of  `circle` to the `map`-property of  `marker` instead:

```js
function init() {
  var randLatLng = function() {
      return new google.maps.LatLng(((Math.random() * 17000 - 8500) / 100), ((Math.random() * 36000 - 18000) / 100));
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
      }
    }),
    markers = [],
    markerCluster;
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    (function() {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: randLatLng()
        }),
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({

          radius: 30.48,
          fillColor: '#FACC2E',
          strokeColor: '#000000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.75,
          strokeWeight: 20
        });
      circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
      circle.bindTo('map', marker, 'map');
      markers.push(marker);
    })();


  }
  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=init" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-marker-clusterer/1.0.0/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and time.  This answer seems to be "drawing" circles though for each marker location still (not just "visible" markers) based on the runtime on my data set of about 12,000 markers.  If I enable the circle, it takes much longer than if the circle is not a part of the javascript code.

Comment: Then listen for the `map_changed`-event of the markers. When the map-property changes to null, remove the circle(when there is any), otherwise draw a circle

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a fast load time:

I added a `zoom_changed` event listener and am only drawing the circles when zoomed in further than a desired level (zoom level of 15 in my example here based on the small radius size of my circles).

I then look for markers in the current viewport and bind a circle object to each of those markers only instead of the entire dataset.

```
// Draw circles when zoomed in close enough - only on markers in viewport.
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {

    if (map.getZoom() > 15){

        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
                if( map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition()) ){

                    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        map: map,
                        radius: 30.48,    // 150 feet in metres
                        fillColor: '#FACC2E',
                        fillOpacity: 0.15,
                        strokeColor: '#FACC2E',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.75
                    });
                    circle.bindTo('center', markers[i], 'position');
                    circle.bindTo('map', markers[i], 'map');
                }
        }
    }
});
```